# Mixed italicization with unicode-math

Tags: unicode-math

The package `unicode-math` provides four options to determine whether Latin and Greek  letters should be printed upright or in italics, depending on their letter case. The mixed styles available are `TeX` (*x*, *X*, *ξ*, Ξ) and `French` (*x*, X, ξ, Ξ).

On æsthetic grounds, I like to use a hybrid style with italic lowercase and upright uppercase (*x*, X, *ξ*, Ξ), which I am currently implementing by forcing correct italicisation via `\itxi` etc. This is less than ideal.  Is there a way to have my stylistic preference as a package-wide option, short of redefining all lowercase greek letters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the standard method to get a new package option is to check on ctan or in the documentation for a suitable tracker (in this case http://github.com/wspr/unicode-math) and to make a feature request.

Beside this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\bool_gset_true:N \g__um_upLatin_bool
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
$xX\beta\Beta$

\end{document}
```

This uses an internal bool (as one can see by the two underscores in the name), so it is not an official method, and should not be relied on to stay stable.

[image]